# Rasdial on Windows 7 Professional 64bit - This function is not supported on this system

Tags: command-line, vpn, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run a simple command prompt line to connect to an existing VPN connection. From a command prompt, I type:

```
rasdial /?
```

...and can see the rasdial help fine. So, then I try the following command with my real information in the right spots:

```
rasdial "MYVPNNAMEHERE" "MYNETWORK\MYUSERNAME" "MYPASSWORD"
```

But I get the following error:

```
This function is not supported on this system
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my own question.
Passing the network name in the username is what was causing the error.
The correct syntax is:

```
rasdial "MYVPNNAMEHERE" "MYUSERNAME" "MYPASSWORD" /DOMAIN:MYNETWORK
```

I hope this helps someone.